# Expansion of brackets for matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

My linear algebra professor proved that $$(Ax) \cdot y = x \cdot (By) \enspace \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \; \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^m$$ for $A$ being an $m \times n$-matrix and $B = A^T$ using the definitions of the dot product and matrix multiplication. During his proof he expanded the brackets of $\sum_{j}x_j\left(\sum_{i}B_{ji}y_{i}\right)$ into $\sum_{i,j}B_{ji}x_{j}y_{i}$.

I don't understand why it is allowed to change the order of multiplication here since, generally, it is not allowed with matrix multiplication. Is the proof incorrect or am I missing something (probably the latter)?

Comment: While the matrices don't commute, their elements are just real numbers. These certainly do commute.

Comment: @Semiclassical you have no idea how stupid I feel now haha. Time to get me a cup of coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your teacher is correct. You can see in another way:

$$(Ax,y)=\sum_{j}y_{j}\left(\sum_{i}A_{ij}x_i\right) \quad (1)$$

$$(x,A^Ty)=\sum_{j}x_{j}\left(\sum_{i}A_{ij}^{T}y_i\right)= \sum_{j}x_{j}\left(\sum_{i}A_{ji}y_i\right) \quad (2)$$

Make $j=p$ at $(1)$ and $i=p$ at $(2)$. You get the same element in both sum:

From $(1)$

$$y_{p}\left(\sum_{i}A_{ip}x_i\right)=\sum_{i}A_{ip}y_{p}x_i$$

From $(2)$

$$\sum_{j}x_{j}A_{jp}y_p$$

See that those are the same. And can do that for every element in each sum.